# Difference between Xcode's file adding options

Tags: ios, xcode

I was just working with a sample project that uses Tesseract OCR library. I followed compiling and building the library as it was mentioned in the [link](http://lois.di-qual.net/blog/install-and-use-tesseract-on-ios-with-tesseract-ios/). There the author mentioned precisely to add files one by creating groups and other by creating references. At times we need to carefully check these values or else you will fail to compile. What is actually going on? I just want to know the reasons behind choosing each particular option?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you choose `Create groups` the files will actually be located in one folder, but in Xcode they will appear grouped the way you had them in the folders.

If you choose `Create folder` Xcode will create folders in your project directory and the structure will be like the structure of the imported folder/folders.